# PDF to text convertor

Tags: linux, macos, pdf, software-rec

I'm looking for a "one-click" way of taking ANY PDF and converting it to plain text.  Ideally on OSX or Linux.

Ideally, the solution would include OCR functionality, but it need not necessarily.

The top priority is having something that can take ANY file WITHOUT configuration.

Comment: This would better suit to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's [xpdf](http://foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) which includes the `pdftotext` binary.

> Pdftotext converts Portable Document Format (PDF) files to plain text.

On Linux there's a installer available. It seems that it also comes in the `poppler-utils` package. On OS X you could install it using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) (install that first) and then use

```
brew install homebrew/x11/xpdf
```

which will download the source files and compile it for OS X. After that, just use it like:

```
pdftotext your_pdf_file.pdf
```

which will generate a plain text file. There are a couple of options as well, check out `man pdftotext` for more details.

An alternative is [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/), in OSX:

```
brew install poppler
```

in Debian and friends

```
apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Comment: as of today the command is `brew install homebrew/x11/xpdf`

Comment: @DiegoVieira Thanks. Next time feel free to suggest an edit!

Comment: some advantage using poppler instead of xpdf/pdftotext?

Comment: `brew install Caskroom/cask/pdftotext`

Answer (score 0):

A nice tool for Windows is [A-PDF Text Extractor](http://www.a-pdf.com/text/index.htm)